# ResponseEntity does not respond for .status when handling validation errors

Tags: spring

I have my `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions over my Rest API.
It looks like that:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleValidtionErrors(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(ex.getBindingResult());
    }
```

It is ok that I have 400 when I want it, but I can replace `return ResponseEntity.badRequest()` with `return ResponseEntity.ok()` and it will still have HTTP Status 400.

What am I doing wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your method with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)` to make it return 200 OK in this case. Take a look at this

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html

It also states,

> The status code is applied to the HTTP response when the handler
>   method is invoked and overrides status information set by other means,
>   like ResponseEntity or "redirect:".

And I believe this is the reason why you are still getting 400 Bad Request even when you are using `return ResponseEntity.OK`